# Boolean Logic with If case

Tags: boolean-logic

There are 2 cases given in the question and on that basis we have to answer.

Cases:

1. if((NOT(value>=1) OR NOT(value<=10))
2. if((NOT(value>=1) AND NOT(value<=10))

Now the questions are:

1. which case you are going to use if the given value either is 1 or 10 ?
2. which case you are going to use if the given value must be  1 or 10   ?

the problem is whether I takes 1 or 10 I am getting same answer in both the cases.  That is if(0) and thus if statement is false in both the cases.?

Comment: where is the switch statement?

Comment: There is no switch statement. It is just 2 different boolean cases

Comment: why you don't try first to clean the code? try to remove the NOT's by mixing them with the (xxx)

Comment: @gian1200..Sorry I didn't get it. I have tried solving but getting the same answer with OR and AND

Comment: is like maths. (-1)*(3+6) =>(-3-6).  Booleans have a similar behavior

Comment: that means both the cases are same..and the answer to both the questions then.is same.? Is not there is rule with AND in C that it evaluates left operand first then right depending on the result

Comment: Yes, if the first condition is false, the second doesn't need to be evaluated.  Similarly, with an OR, if the first condition evaluates true, the second will not need to be evaluated.  At least where I've looked into it (C, C++, Java).  I'd say it's very likely that some languages evaluate both conditions even if the second isn't necessary to determine the correct boolean result.

Comment: That's called [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), by the way.

Comment: That's true, however your problem is not that, is that your if-statement will always return false if value=10 or 1. I don't want to give you the answer, but I recommend you to read about "De Morgan's laws". As I told you before, try to simplify your if-statement until you get something like "if(A OR B)"

Comment: @gian I have used De morgan law..but we are not supposed to use that..because it is C question and in language whether it is valid or not..i don't know..Infact whether you use law or not answer remains the same

Comment: it does, because you can simplify your cases:
case 1.-if((NOT(value>=1) OR NOT(value<=10)) can be written as if(value<1 OR value>10). Which means that you will never get true if value is 1<=value<=10

Comment: yeah.equation simplfy but answer remains the same and I know that if is always false..that's what I have written in question's last line.

Comment: as an aside, for use with C (as mentioned above) "AND" and "OR" would need to be translated into C language operators.  C has "&&" and "||", which are the boolean short circuit operators, as well as "&" and "|", which are bitwise boolean operators.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(NOT(value>=1) OR NOT(value<=10)) = (value < 1) OR (value > 10)`

This case is true for [-Infinity ... 0] or [11 ... + Infinity]
Is false for 1 or 10

1. `((NOT(value>=1) AND NOT(value<=10)) = (value < 1) AND (value > 10)`

This case is always false, as no number can be smaller than 1 and bigger than 10 the same time.